# Font face rendering on Firefox 17 for Mac

Tags: firefox, fonts, icons, font-face

This happens only on Firefox for Mac. I tested Chrome, Opera, Safari, Firefox (Mac 10.7.5) and IE9 and Firefox ‎(Win7).

Firefox 17 on Mac OSX 10.7.5 (both local and remote) renders icons generated with FontSquirrel blurry, bold... I don't know... here is a screenshot: https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/18823_4937015794180_273981630_n.jpg

Here is my css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'forteregular';
src: url('fonts/forte-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/forte-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/forte-webfont.svg#forteregular') format('svg'),
     url('fonts/forte-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/forte-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

Anyone? Thanks